# Is it still possible to create a paid extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

In the Web Store Developer Dashboard, I see no way to set the price for an extension I am uploading. Am I missing something? Or is it no longer possible to create a paid extension? I saw an article saying they were removing paid extensions in January but there are still paid extensions on the store.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got an email yesterday from `chromewebstore-dev-support@google.com` that included this info:
**Chrome Web Store payments - We are disabling the ability to create new paid items or add payments to existing items. This includes extensions, themes, apps, and in-app purchases.**

Here is the full text of the email:

> Dear Developer,
>
> We want to tell you about impending changes to the Chrome Web Store as
> a result of the COVID-19 situation.
>
> Given adjusted work schedules due to these unprecedented times, there
> may be some temporary limitations and delays in support in some cases:
>
> **Delay in publishing** - New versions submitted to the Store will take longer to be reviewed and published.
>
> **Delay in responses to appeals** - If you appeal an item rejection or removal, or appeal an account suspension, expect the response to be
> delayed. However, we will respond to every appeal request and we will
> get back to you as soon as we can.
>
> **Delay in developer account transfers** - If you are transferring your extension to a different account, expect a significant increase
> in the time taken to complete the transfer.
>
> **Delay in general support** - If you are trying to reach out to our support team for issues related to your account(s) or extension(s),
> expect a delayed response from our team. We will get back to you as
> soon as we can.
>
> **Chrome Web Store payments** - We are disabling the ability to create new paid items or add payments to existing items. This includes
> extensions, themes, apps, and in-app purchases.
>
> You can help by making sure that your extensions comply with the
> Developer program policies before you submit them. Refer to these
> resources for more information:
>
> Help center articles
> chromium-extensions Google Group
> StackOverflow
> Chrome support forum
>
> We understand that these changes may cause inconvenience, and we
> apologize for any interruption of service. Thank you for your support
> during this challenging time and for your participation in the Chrome
> extension ecosystem.
>
> The Google Chrome Web Store team

Sorry about the formatting.

Comment: I see, so this is just a COVID-19 thing then? Do you know if it had been disabled before that?

Comment: I don't think so, my extension is not paid so it does not concern me.

Comment: @SethSetse just before COVID-related restrictions Chrome Team had some problems with fraudulent transactions in Web Store. Publishing of paid items was temporarily disabled in the period from January 2020 till 20 March 2020. You can find more details in this discussion https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-extensions/EW0VuDjZSO4.

Comment: @SethSetse And seems that we can wait for some updates about current COVID-related restrictions in this thread https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-extensions/r5EKL-McE3A.