# Chrome extension: no pricing options when publishing

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to upload and publish a chrome extension I've made with a simple one-time payment. I've found [this article](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/overview#builtin) which makes me think I should just have pricing options on the upload page. I've hooked up my merchant account and set a valid payment method, as well as verified it but I still don't get any pricing options--when I load the page, the pricing options appear for a moment and are then replaced with just the distribution region checkboxes. Any ideas for solving this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it still possible to create a paid extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60956946/is-it-still-possible-to-create-a-paid-extension)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is the same issue with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60957801/3549173)

> Chrome Web Store payments - We are disabling the ability to create new paid items or add payments to existing items. This includes extensions, themes, apps, and in-app purchases.